# Why doesn't Internet Explorer render this page smoothly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, render

Have a look at this page in IE 8:
http://labs.pieterdedecker.be/hetoog/layout.htm

It looks okay at first, but try hovering over an item and then taking your mouse off the item grid again.

**Before**

[image: Before]

**After**

[image: After]

Notice how there's a black border on the right of the yellow item. Also, the font looks different.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I cannot check IE8, because I'm working on a mac. You can check if your site is valid: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Flabs.pieterdedecker.be%2Fhetoog%2Flayout.htm&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0.

Comment: use a this in your script tag:
<script>
<![CDATA[
// script 
]]>
</script>

Comment: I don't think this is related to the validity of the document, but because of the buggy opacity filter in IE8. Did you try with .css("-ms-filter", "alpha(opacity=20)") ? This is the new syntax for the filters in IE8.

Comment: Looks all fine to me using IE 7 and 8 on Windows 7.

Comment: I have an offset of 1 pixel on IE8/Win7, like on the screenshot.

Comment: This is a perfect example as to why it is required to post the markup, errors, code, and anything else within the question and not a link to a third party site: [mcve]

Comment: People still look for Stack Overflow threads about IE8 in 2019?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would put all my money on that it's due to your table based layout... try using DIVs instead.

here's a rough example of replacing all your tables/cells with divs:

http://jsbin.com/akido/

test it in IE8 and you'll see you no longer have the altering issue...

Answer (score 1):

You should try removing the table-layout:fixed property assigned to table.grid in your CSS, I read somewhere that can cause bugs in IE8. (Should be unnecessary since it looks like you've assigned widths to each td.)

As an aside, you should really consider using more dividing things up into more than one class in the future. Instead of  try  so you can write CSS like td.note{} instead of td.brownnote, td.greennote, ...{}